# Make .app file in Xcode with UDID of device

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode6

Is it possible to add a device remotely in Xcode with UDID, I do have developers account and device added there, i want to access that device in another MAC with UDID number in Xcode to generate product .app file!

Is it possible? Please help me!

Thank you in Advance!

Comment: If you have added the device to developer account, you just need to add the certificates and provisioning profiles to that other mac. Refer these documents,

http://www.aquafadas.com/en/documentation/sample-page/developer-apple-com-2/

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have added the device to developer account, you just need to add the certificates and provisioning profiles to that other mac. Refer [these](http://www.aquafadas.com/en/documentation/sample-page/developer-apple-com-2/) documents,

Hope this will help you to figure it out.